# passing data from mat-table to mat-card in same component

Tags: angular, parameter-passing, mat-table

I have a component with a mat-table, and I'm able to use the variables in my datasource in the html file. My table has an expansion panel which opens to a mat-card. There I also need to pass parameters, from the same class that is used for the datasource. While I am easily able to access the parameters, I want them to be filtered by a specific field, but I don't know how to do that. I know that Angular, it is advisable to use pipes for filtering; however, I don't know how to pass this particular field so that I can then apply the filter. Basically, I want the data to be filtered by this.jobUuid. I've tried an if statement a few different ways, but it doesn't work. While I can easily create a pipe, how do I pass this.jobUuid to to the pipe. I hope my question is clear. Below is my code.
html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form>
    <mat-form-field color="warn" class="input2">
      <input matInput [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="dateValue"
             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (dateChange)="callJobService(dateValue)">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div class="input1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" (click)="refreshDate()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>Refresh
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="input1">
      <mat-form-field color="warn" appearance="legacy">
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="report-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="processStatus">
        <mat-header-cell class=col1 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class=col1 *matCellDef="let job">{{job.processStatus}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="startTime">
        <mat-header-cell class=col2 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Start Time</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class=col2 *matCellDef="let job">{{job.startTime| date :'medium'}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="endTime">
        <mat-header-cell class=col3 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>End Time</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class=col3 *matCellDef="let job">{{job.endTime| date :'medium'}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="numberOfReports">
        <mat-header-cell class=col4 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Number of Reports</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class=col4 *matCellDef="let job">{{job.reportCount}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="numberOfBatches">
        <mat-header-cell class=col5 *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Number of Batches</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class=col5 *matCellDef="let job">{{job.batchCount}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container class=col6 matColumnDef="addArrow">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let job">
          <mat-icon (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === job ? null : job">expand_more</mat-icon>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #tpl let-job>
        <div class="mat-row detail-row" [@detailExpand] style="overflow: hidden">
          <mat-card class="card1">
            <mat-card-title>Input -> Batches</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-actions>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" mat-raised-button (click)="collapsed=false">Show batch details</button>
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" mat-raised-button (click)="collapsed=true">Hide batch details</button>
              </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed">
              <div *ngFor="let job of jobs">
                <div *ngFor="let batchList of job.batchList let jobUuid = index">
                  <p class="title"><b>Batch ID:</b> {{batchList.batchId}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>Event Type:</b> {{batchList.eventType}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>Data Path:</b> {{batchList.dataPath}}</p>
                  <br>
                </div>
              </div>
            </mat-card-content>
            <br>
          </mat-card>
          <mat-card class="card1">
            <mat-card-title>Output -> Reports</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-actions>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" mat-raised-button (click)="collapsed2=false">Show report details</button>
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" mat-raised-button (click)="collapsed2=true">Hide report details</button>
              </mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed2">
              <div *ngFor="let job of jobs">
                  <div *ngFor="let reportList of filterByVariable(job, jobUuid">
                    <p class="title"><b>Transfer Status:</b> {{reportList.transferStatus}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>File Size:</b> {{reportList.fileSize}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>Last Updated:</b> {{reportList.lastUpdate | date :'medium'}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>ADLS Full Path:</b> {{reportList.adlsPath}}</p>
                  <!--                  <br>-->
                  <button class="button-download" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" (click)="downloadFile(reportList.adlsPath)">Download File
                  </button>
                  <br><br>
<!--                  </div>-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </mat-card-content>
            <br>
          </mat-card>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedReportsColumn"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedReportsColumn;" matRipple
               class="element-row" [cdkDetailRow]="row"
               [cdkDetailRowTpl]="tpl">
      </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

component

```
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {from} from 'rxjs';
import {DownloadFileService} from "../../services/download-file.service";
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material/table";
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';
import {JobService} from "../../services/job.service";
import {Job} from "../../models/Job";
import {BatchList} from "../../models/batchList";
import {ReportList} from "../../models/reportList";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-output',
  templateUrl: './jobs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobs.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('void', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden'})),
      state('*', style({height: '*', visibility: 'visible'})),
      transition('void <=> *', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ])
  ],
})
export class JobsComponent implements OnInit {

  jobs: Job[];
  // batchLists: BatchList[];
  // reportLists: ReportList[];
  dateValue = new Date();
  maxDate = new Date();
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Job>;
  expandedElement: Job | null;
  collapsed = true;
  collapsed2 = true;
  displayedReportsColumn: string[] = ['processStatus', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'numberOfReports', 'numberOfBatches', 'addArrow'];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  isExpansionDetailRow = (index, row) => row.hasOwnProperty('detailRow');



  constructor(private jobService: JobService, private downloadFileService: DownloadFileService, private datePipe: DatePipe) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.callJobService(new Date());
  }

  callJobService(value: Date) {
    this.jobService.mergeReportJob(value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.jobs = <Job[]><unknown>res;
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.jobs));
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.jobs);
        // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter) => {
      const dataStr = JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase();
      return dataStr.indexOf(filter) != -1;
    }
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

filterbyVariable(job: Job, jobUuid: string) {
return job. reportList.filter(r=> r.Uuid == jobUuid)


  refreshDate() {
    this.callJobService(this.dateValue);
  }

  downloadFile(pathToDownload) {
    console.log(pathToDownload);
    from(this.downloadFileService.downloadFile({'pathToDownload': pathToDownload}))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        saveAs(new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}), (pathToDownload.substring(pathToDownload.indexOf('part'))));
      })
  }
}
```

service file

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {AppConfig} from "../app.config";
import {DatePipe} from "@angular/common";
import {Job} from "../models/Job";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JobService {
  private apiUrl = '';
  private jobsEndPoint = '';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private appConfig: AppConfig, public datePipe: DatePipe) {
    this.apiUrl = this.appConfig.settings.apiServer.apiUrl;
    this.jobsEndPoint = this.appConfig.settings.apiServer.jobsEndPoint;
  }

  mergeReportJob(date: Date) {
    const transfomedDate = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyyMMdd');
    const body = `date = ${date}`;
    return this.http.post<Job[]>(`${this.apiUrl}${this.jobsEndPoint}?date=${transfomedDate}`, body)

  }

}
```

class file

```
import {ReportList} from "./reportList";

export class Job {
  jobUuid: string;
  businessDate: string;
  dataSource: string;
  eventType: string;
  reportName: string;
  processStatus: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  batchCount: number;
  reportCount: number;
  batchList: BatchList[];
  reportList: ReportList[];
}
```

Comment: Which data exactly do you want to filter, is it the reportList?

Comment: yes, the reportList. actually, it's both the reportList and the batchList, but once I know how to do one, I'm sure I can do the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have it right (which I might not) you want to filter the displayed reportList items to the ones that contain the jobUuid.

If so you could can use a function to filter the data in your *ngFor.

[Quick StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzonyq).

```
<mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed2">
              <div *ngFor="let job of jobs; let jobUuid = index">
                  <div *ngFor="let reportList of filteredReports(jobUuid)">
<!--                    <div *ngIf="reportList.jobUuid==jobUuid">-->
                    <p class="title"><b>Transfer Status:</b> {{reportList.transferStatus}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>File Size:</b> {{reportList.fileSize}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>Last Updated:</b> {{reportList.lastUpdate | date :'medium'}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>ADLS Full Path:</b> {{reportList.adlsPath}}</p>
                  <!--                  <br>-->
                  <button class="button-download" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" (click)="downloadFile(reportList.adlsPath)">Download File
                  </button>
                  <br><br>
<!--                  </div>-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </mat-card-content>
```

ts:

```
 filteredReports(id)
{
    return this.jobs.find(j => j.jobUuid == id).reportList.filter(r => r.jobUuid == id);
}
```

Or pass the job into the function to filter directly on that job, and whatever else you need, depends what you want to filter on:

component:

```
  <div *ngFor="let reportList of filteredReports(job)">
```

ts:

```
 filteredReports(job: Job)
{
    return job.reportList.filter(r => r.jobUuid == job.Uuid);
}
```

Not sure if that is what you are filtering on exactly but it gives the idea.

Comment: the trouble with this code, is that if I remove the inner loop (<div *ngFor="let reportList of job.reportList">, and I put this :                     <div *ngFor="let reportList of filterByVariable(jobUuid)">, I get an error that reportList is undefined. The jobs object is a jsonObject coming from my api, and is not actually in the component (like your Stackblitz example)

Comment: Ok, just you have  this.jobs = <Job[]><unknown>res; in your component so looks like this.jobs holds the data from the api called in ngOnInit. Also, you may need to alter the filtering function depending on what you need it to do, it is just an example of a way to filter. E.g. if this.jobs has data and in your function you do return this.jobs[0].reportList; then that should be a test of if the filter would work in principal. To answer the question of how to pass a parameter to component for filtering.

Comment: Also see edited answer for additional function example.

Comment: Thanks JMP for the help. I was still not able to make it work. I wonder if it is because my jobUuid is a string not a number and can therefore not be used as an index          
(let reportListof job.reportListof let jobUuid = index")

Comment: just to clarify, I need to filter the reportList by the Uuid, which is the same as the jobUuid in the class Job

Comment: I've now edited my original code to reflect the changes you suggested as far as I can understand them, but it doesn't let me pass jobUuid, it turns red. (since I can't use it as an index because the type is string)

Comment: Ok so if you pass only the job as a parameter, you can use the jobUuid in that job parameter to then filter on the report list and get rid of the index. See second function in answer.

Comment: There is no uuid property in the job class you’ve posted though so that has caused me confusion. Also because you were trying to create a uuid using the index but you say the job class has uuid.  Hopefully you’ve enough to go on to work it though now.

Comment: Glad its sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
filterByVariable(job: Job) {
    return job.reportList.filter(r=> r.jobUuid == job.jobUuid)
  }


            <mat-card-content *ngIf="!collapsed2">
                <div *ngFor="let reportList of filterByVariable(job)">
                  <p class="title"><b>Transfer Status:</b> {{reportList.transferStatus}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>File Size:</b> {{reportList.fileSize}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>Last Updated:</b> {{reportList.lastUpdate | date :'medium'}}</p>
                  <p class="title"><b>ADLS Full Path:</b> {{reportList.adlsPath}}</p>
                  <!--                  <br>-->
                  <button class="button-download" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" (click)="downloadFile(reportList.adlsPath)">Download File
                  </button>
                  <br><br>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
```